# Method/class to call instead of pushviewcontroller for iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table view app that im coding for a course that supposed to work in iPhone/iPad. I can get the phone part working fine and split view on ipad is fine, but i can't get the view controller on the right to change when i select an item in the popover. Here is my code from the MasterViewController.m:

```
#pragma mark - Sal's Methods

-(void) doAbout {
   NSLog(@"About");

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    AboutMe *vc = [[AboutMe alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutMe" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    } else {
    AboutMe *vc = [[AboutMe alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutMe_iPad" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }



}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UISplitViewController *svc = self.splitViewController;
DetailViewController *rightVC = [svc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        [self doAbout];
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"Concurrency");
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"Sandbox");
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"Notification");
        break;
    case 4:
        NSLog(@"Email");
        break;
    case 5:
        NSLog(@"Mapkit");
        break;
    case 6:
        NSLog(@"Animate");
        break;
    case 7:
        NSLog(@"Contacts");
        break;
    case 8:
        NSLog(@"SQLlite");
        break;
    case 9:
        NSLog(@"Core Data");
        break;

    default:
        break;
}




}

@end
```

Comment: Are you saying you want your AboutMe view controller to appear in the split view controller's detail view when the user taps the first row in your master view controller's table view?